# Adding widgets to a screen subclass in .py file

Tags: python, kivy

I am using a screen manager and would like to add widgets to the screen subclass without using the .kv file.

```
class MainMenu(Screen):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        gLayout = GridLayout()
        gLayout.add_widget(Button(text = 'test'))

class Sis(App):
     def build(self):
         root = ScreenManager()
         root.add_widget(MainMenu(name = 'mainMenu'))
         root.current = 'mainMenu'

         return root

 Sis().run()
```

When I try to run the above code I get `(pygame parachute) Segmentation Fault`.

If I create the layout in the .kv file it works fine.

I've tried fiddling around with `on_pre_enter` and `on_enter` but I'm pretty sure I was using them wrong.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot calling parent constructor of MainMenu class:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class MainMenu(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainMenu, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add_widget(Button(text = 'test'))      


class Sis(App):
     def build(self):
         root = ScreenManager()
         root.add_widget(MainMenu(name = 'mainMenu'))
         root.current = 'mainMenu'
         return root

Sis().run()
```

Comment: That sorted it. I'm off to read up on `super`. Thanks for the help.